# TCpdf generate PDF without ICC

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

We need to generate a PDF for press usage. We are not allowed to use ICC profiles. The TCPDF libary always generates ICC profile PDF's. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Made a few changes to make your question easier to read and hopefully more attractive to answerers.